# If statement within else statement in scala?

Tags: scala

I have a method below (note I have simplified to make question simpler)

```
def getMyInt(flag1: Boolean, flag2: Boolean): Int = {
  if (flag1) 0;
  else {
    if (flag2) 1;
    if (flag2) 2;
  }
```

}

Problem is that even though inner `if` expression returns Ints, the `else` that wraps will return `Unit`. And hence I get:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- type mismatch; found : Unit 
 required: Int
```

Any tips?

Comment: but your method can not return int. what if neither flag1 and flag2 are true?

Comment: If an `if` expression has no `else` part, it's as if you wrote `if (cond) value else ()` (the `()` is the literal notation for the `Unit` value). The type of an `if` expression is the LUB (most specific common supertype) of each of its "sides."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try wrapping `flag1` and `flag2` in a `Tuple` and  pattern match on that.

```
def getMyInt(flag1: Boolean, flag2: Boolean): Int = (flag1, flag2) match {
  case (true, _) => 0
  case (_, true) => 1
  //Other cases
}
```

Also, control flags as parameters [smell funny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). Martin Fowler has an [article](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html) on refactoring flag arguments.

Answer (score 3):

If none of the if statements in your inner else statement apply, nothing can be returned. Change your code to as follows and it will compile:

```
def getMyInt(flag1: Boolean, flag2: Boolean): Int = if (flag1) 0
  else {
    if (flag2) 1
    else 2
  }
```

I change the second if statement in the inner else because two times if flag2 doesn't make sense.